# How to extract specific key,value pairs from list of lists and add it to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am working with JSON formated dataframe (read_json). I need to extract specific value from list of list inside of one of dataframe columns and append it as new columns.

**My DF:**

```
df_with_name.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 286 entries, 500px to youtube.com
Data columns (total 7 columns):
documents    286 non-null object
logo         286 non-null object
name         286 non-null object
points       286 non-null object
rated        286 non-null object
see          2 non-null object
slug         286 non-null object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 27.9+ KB
```

Where column ***points*** contains list of list, which I can access like this:

```
df_with_name['points'][4]
```

*Prints column points from df_with_name in 3rd position.*

**Output:**

```
[{'description': '“500px reserves the right, at its sole discretion, to modify or replace the terms at any time. If the alterations constitute a material change to the terms, 500px will notify you by Posting an announcement on the site. What constitutes a material change will be Determined at 500px’s sole discretion.”',
  'discussion': 'https://edit.tosdr.org/points/995',
  'id': '995',
  'point': 'bad',
  'score': 70,
  'title': ' Terms may be changed any time at their discretion, without notice to the user '},
 {'description': '“500px may terminate your store account at any time for any reason or no reason. All Store Images remaining in your Store account will be removed by 500px upon termination of your store account.”',
  'discussion': 'https://edit.tosdr.org/points/891',
  'id': '891',
  'point': 'bad',
  'score': 60,
  'title': '500px Store: your account can be terminated at any time'}]
```

**What do I want to accomplish:**

How can I access key value pair of ***'title', 'score' and 'point'*** for each of 286 entries in dataframe and append them to dataframe as new columns (or create new dataframe from them)?

**What I tried:**

If I specify singular entry from dataframe as dictionary I can access interesting key value pairs, like this:

```
df_as_dict['points'][1]['title']
```

I can also then loop using `.get()`, like this:

```
for v in df_as_dict.get('points'):
    print(v.get('title'))
```

But this somehow fails when I try to put everything together or works only on slices of dataframe (singular entry, not the whole df).

What am I missing? Where my logic is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `l` is your `list`

```
pd.DataFrame(l)
```